# How to add .sld or .qml to .GPKG containing rasters using python

Tags: python, raster, gdal, style, geopackage

I'm looking for a pythonic way to add style layers to a Geopackage. I've checked out [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/273750/is-there-any-way-to-include-universal-style-symbology-in-geopackage/276175#276175) and [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268746/writing-style-information-into-geopackage-with-python-and-gdal/268766#268766), and both show how to do it in QGIS gui but not Python. I have a .sld file and want to add it to the GPKG as the default style. Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

I've tried

```
trans_kwargs = {
    'format':'GPKG'
}
creation_options = ['APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES']
gdal.Translate('test.gpkg', 'test_style.sld', **trans_kwargs, creationOptions=creation_options)
```

but get the following error.

`ValueError: Received a NULL pointer.`